# Decorators vs. classes in python web development

Tags: python, django, pylons, tornado, bottle

I've noticed three main ways Python web frameworks deal request handing: decorators, controller classes with methods for individual requests, and request classes with methods for GET/POST.

I'm curious about the virtues of these three approaches. Are there major advantages or disadvantages to any of these approaches?  To fix ideas, here are three examples.

[Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/) uses decorators:

```
@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

[Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/gettingstarted/) uses controller classes:

```
class HelloController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        return 'Hello World'
```

[Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation) uses request handler classes with methods for types:

```
 class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")
```

Which style is the best practice?

Comment: You tagged it with Django and didn't include a sample. I would argue Django is *the* Python web framework so it seems a little odd to exclude it even if its MVT approach is a little different from standard MVC models.

Comment: Django isn't your go-to framework to see Python best practices.

Comment: Perhaps not but I'm not sure there's such a thing as a best practise at this level.

Comment: There may not be a "best practice" at this level, but there is an opposite, and Django's a good candidate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's actually a reason for each of the three methods you listed, specific to each project.

- Bottle tries to keep things as
  simple/straightforward as possible
  for the programmer.  With decorators
  for routes you don't have to worry
  about the developer understanding OOP.
- Pylons development goal is to make
  code re-usable and to be easily
  integrated with WSGI-style HTTP
  process routing.  As such, they have
  chosen a very OOP way of organizing
  routes.  As an example, you could
  copy & paste HelloController into any
  Pylons app and it should just
  magically work.  Even if said app is
  being served up via WSGI in some
  complicated fashion.
- Tornado has yet another reason for
  doing things the way it does: 
  Tornado's epoll-based IOLoop (in conjunction with tornado.web.Application)
  instantiates each RequestHandler as
  requests come in.  By keeping each
  RequestHandler limited to a specific
  GET or POST this allows IOLoop to
  quickly instantiate the class,
  process the request, and finally let
  it get garbage collected.  This keeps
  it fast and efficient with a small
  memory footprint regardless of how
  many RequestHandlers your application
  has.  This is also the reason why Tornado can handle so many more simultaneous requests than other Python-based web servers (each request gets its own instance).

Now, having said all that you should know that you can always override the default framework behavior.  For example, I wrote a [MethodDispatcher](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576958-method-based-url-dispatcher-for-the-tornado-web-se/) for Tornado that makes it work more like Pylons (well, I had CherryPy in mind when I wrote it).  It slows down Tornado a tiny amount (and increases the memory footprint slightly) due to having one large RequestHandler (as opposed to a lot of small ones) but it can reduce the amount of code in your app and make it a little easier to read (In my biased opinion, of course =).

Answer (score 1):

The various frameworks are trying to achieve the best performance through the best code (for writing and reading). They each adopt different strategies based on or around MVC or MVT.

What you're focussing on will probably come down to personal taste. And so will my answer. I'm trying very hard to avoid any sort of holy war because there may be valid technical arguments that I just don't know about.

But I *personally* prefer to keep the routing separate from the controller (django's view) and templating separate from that. It makes reusing controllers really simple. Yeah, I'm a Django user.

As such, I'm really not a big fan of Bottle's decorators or wrapping things in great big hulking classes. I used to when I was an ASP.NET dev but Django set me free.

Comment: I agree that it's nice to separate routing from controllers. This makes it possible to automate routing based on your preferences. There's no explicit need to come up with exact urls always. :)